# In magento how to list out category list in left side bar of product page

Tags: magento

I need to list out the categories in sidebar navigation.How to display the category list in sidebar navigation.

Comment: have you try to find solution from google?

Comment: Yes i have got the sidebar by following this link [http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/changing-the-page-layout]  but i cant able to list out the categories in sidebar.

Comment: Have you assign product to some brand or manufacturer? or your custom attribute?

Comment: I have just added my product under default attribute

Comment: I have made categories to display in sidebar using the extension from this link [http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-professional.html] but i cant able to display the products list under category.is it possible with this plugin..

Comment: it display only category not product

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42859/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-keyur-shah)